# Esper Grouping Causes Duplicates

Tags: esper

I have a basic Esper query as follows:

```
@Name("MyTestQuery")
@Description("My First Test Query")
select sum(qty), venue
from MyTestWindow
group by venue
```

The query seems to duplicate the results of my sum i.e. if I send in a qty of 10 my query will fire multiple times and output:

10, 20, 30, 40

However, if I remove the group by function then it just outputs 10.

Is anyone able to advise why this might happen?

Comment: Sounds like your application sends the event 4 times

Answer (score 0):

Typically you need to qualify the Stream name (MyTestWindow) with a window, so it is 
"from MyTestWindow.win:time(1 sec) ". You need to select an appropriate window type from many Epser offers, depending on your application.

This example:

```
select sum(qty), venue
  from MyTestWindow.win:time_batch(1 sec)
 group by venue
   having sum(qty) is not null
```

You can run a simple test of this at http://esper-epl-tryout.appspot.com/epltryout/mainform.html

Answer (score 0):

the best way of doing a group by is to trigger an artificial "event" after sending in all events. this way you can fully control what you want you want to output and not let Esper's engine run in real time.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to use the "distinct" feature in select to avoid duplicates. Esper can sometimes create duplicate events when you aren't using trigger variables, so distinct will allow you to get rid of unwanted events.

Answer (score -1):

You can use  `win:time_batch` to specified time interval in one update and coalesce function to handle the `null` value

select venue, sum(coalesce(ty, 0))

```
from MyTestWindow.win:time_batch(1 sec)
group by venue
```